# Why Task Parallel Library can update UI simply?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, .net-4.0

When I try update UI using Task in .net Framework 4, I found out that something strange. I never thought UI thread can be updated from Task Library. I just wanted to test it and amazingly it works. Here is my code, can someone explain how it works ?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i=0;
    Task myTask = new Task(() =>
    { 
        while (true) 
        { 
            label1.Text = "Hello" + i++; 
            Thread.Sleep(3000); 
        }; 
    });

    myTask.Start();
}
```

Comment: I would say you're just lucky. :) Perhaps the task is being executed on the UI thread by the task scheduler? I admit that the inner workings of the TPL aren't my forte, though.

Comment: What are the thread ids of the UI thread and of the task?

Comment: Ha ha , true. When I try to run by debug mode and it throw exception. It was just a coincident. Thanks for giving me ideas @Amy.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you didn't get an exception this time doesn't mean that you (or even worse your customer) won't get an exception the next time. You were just lucky. Make sure you marshal all function calls to the UI on the main thread. Or if you want to spare this task use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) which will take care of executing the callback on the main thread.